# How do you bevel on an already beveled edge?

Tags: vertices, edges, bevel

I am following a tutorial for modelling an air conditioning unit, but in the tutorial the person bevels successfully on an already beveled edge with the usual ctrl+B. Here is the screenshot of the video:[image]

However when I try doing the same, the bevel goes all funny,and the lines seam to stretch to the centre:
[image]

I've reset rotation and scale and tried changing settings, but nothing has seemed to have worked. I've heard that you can't bevel on a bevel, but on the tutorial he seems to do just that, so I'm stumped. Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turn off auto-merge vertices at the top of the toolbar next to the XYZ symmetry buttons.

Comment: @Electric_Wizard I've tried that but it hasn't worked

Comment: OK this is very confusing, after saving, closing blender and re-opening blender it has magically worked. This is great but I'm still really confused why this has happened.